# How operate more than one Socket in ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, sockets, listview, visual-studio-2013

I have 2 Sockets in server and client respectively (where client connect to server), on server i have one class that contains some informations of each client like *IP*, *Socket* and *ID*.

For each connection accepted i add the last client connected to this `List`, this way i have a list (that is a object) of clients. And also each client is added in one `ListView` where is assigned the object referent to this client, on **Tag** property of `ListViewItem`. This is one of way that can help later if you want send a message to a specific client.

Like you can see this `List` of clients is referent only to 1 Socket that listen in a determinated port number. Now already that i have 2 Sockets in each side (server and client), how i can make if i want send a message from second `Socket` of server to the second `Socket` on client? for example, is possible assign more than 1 object to **Tag** property of `ListViewItem` (only a idea)?

Below is my code (server, compatible only with 1 `Socket` and 1 object (`List` of client)):

**Form:**

```
namespace mainForm
{

public partial class frmMain : Form
{
Listener server;
Thread start;

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    server = new Listener();
}

private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start = new Thread(listen);
    start.Start();
}

private void listen()
{
    server.BeginListen(101); // Select a port to listen
    server.Received += new Listener.ReceivedEventHandler(server_Received);
    server.Disconnected += new Listener.DisconnectedEventHandler(server_Disconnected);
}

private void server_Disconnected(Listener l, Info i)
{
    Invoke(new _Remove(Remove), i);
}

private void server_Received(Listener l, Info i, string received)
{

    string[] cmd = received.Split('|');
    int inc;

    for (inc = 0; inc < cmd.Length; inc++)
    {

        switch (cmd[inc].ToString())
        {
            case "CMD1":

                Invoke(new _Add(Add), i, cmd[2] + " - " + cmd[3]);

                break;

            case "CMD2":

                 // Other code here

                break;

        }
    }
}

private delegate void _Add(Info i, string computer);
    private void Add(Info i, string computer)
    {
        string[] splitIP = i.RemoteAddress.Split(':');

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = i.ID.ToString();
        item.SubItems.Add(splitIP[0]);
        item.SubItems.Add(computer);
        item.Tag = i;

        lvConnections.Items.Add(item);

    }

private delegate void _Remove(Info i);
    private void Remove(Info i)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvConnections.Items)
        {
            if ((Info)item.Tag == i)
            {
                item.Remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

private void disconnectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvConnections.SelectedItems)
    {
        Info client = (Info)item.Tag;
        client.Send("DISCONNECT" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

**Listener:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Listener
{
    Socket s;
    public List<Info> clients;

    public delegate void ReceivedEventHandler(Listener l, Info i, string received);
    public event ReceivedEventHandler Received;
    public delegate void DisconnectedEventHandler(Listener l, Info i);
    public event DisconnectedEventHandler Disconnected;

    bool listening = false;

    public Listener()
    {
        clients = new List<Info>();
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public bool Running
    {
        get { return listening; }
    }

    public void BeginListen(int port)
    {
        s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        s.Listen(100);
        s.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), s);
        listening = true;
    }

    public void StopListen()
    {
        if (listening == true)
        {
            s.Close();
            listening = false;
        }
    }

    void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket sock = handler.EndAccept(ar);
        Info i = new Info(sock);
        clients.Add(i);

        sock.BeginReceive(i.buffer, 0, i.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), i);
        handler.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), handler);
    }

    void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Info i = (Info)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            int rec = i.sock.EndReceive(ar);
            if (rec != 0)
            {
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(i.buffer, 0, rec);
                Received(this, i, data);
            }
            else
            {
                Disconnected(this, i);
                return;
            }

            i.sock.BeginReceive(i.buffer, 0, i.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), i);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Disconnected(this, i);
            i.sock.Close();
            clients.Remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Info:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class Info
{
    public Socket sock;
    public Guid ID;
    public string RemoteAddress;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

    public Info(Socket sock)
    {
        this.sock = sock; 
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(); 
        RemoteAddress = sock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(); 
    }

    public void Send(string data)
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        sock.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback((ar) =>
        {
            sock.EndSend(ar);
        }), buffer);
    }
}
```

---

**EDITION:**

*Here is what code above already makes =>*

[image]

*And here is like i wants make (also work with **Socket 02** in a selected client) =>*

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow. You can't assign 2 objects to 1 `Tag` property, however you can assign 1 `List<Socket>` object to 1 `Tag` property.

Comment: @vasily.sib, thank you by comment. Then not have a solution to operate 2 Sockets in same client on `ListView`?

Comment: I was answering specificly this part of your question: _"is possible assign more than 1 object to Tag property of ListViewItem (only a idea)?"_ As for me, I'm trying to avoid using of `Tag` property as long as it possible, or at least store there some primitives (identifiers of objects/keys). Then, I can work with actual objects throught some custom service, which actualy store collection of objects.

Comment: Also as for me `ListView` and `Socket` are to different things, so I think you question need to be rewritten to explain what are you actually asking for.

Comment: @vasily.sib, Like you saw, the code above is able to send a command to specific client (`ListViewItem`) using only **1** `Socket`. `client.Send("DISCONNECT" + "\r\n");` My goal is know how make to this same task using a second Socket? in others words, how i can send a message to specific client of ListView using a second Socket from server, where this message will arrive on second Socket already present on client side? The ListView must support send mesage to specific client, using any Socket (between 2) and not using only 1 Socket like already is made. I hope that you had understood :D

Comment: @vasily.sib, The **"only 1 Socket"** that i'm saying is like this => `IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 100);

Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(100);`

Comment: the whole idea of storing socket handles in tags of UI controls is doomed. there is an UI thread, and there are background threads. they are separated for good reasons (responsive UI) and you should really redefine your architecture to keep network communication separate from visualization, list items can best be updated based on socket status by events that cross the Background/UI thread barrier with `Invoke`. Define a class that deals with the visual representation for the list view, and assign application-wide unique IDs to keep track of which sockets are assigned to which list item.

Comment: @dlatikay, thank you by comment. See my edition above please.